# node.js: mailparser not working

Tags: node.js, email-parsing

I want to parse an email and found mailparser package. (installed it using "npm install mailparser").
i'm using windows 7.
i'm trying to run the simple example but the "end" event is not called and i don't see any logs.
this is what i run:

```js
const MailParser = require("mailparser").MailParser;
const mailparser = new MailParser({debug: true});

let email = "From: 'Sender Name' <sender@example.com>\r\n"+
    "To: 'Receiver Name' <receiver@example.com>\r\n"+
    "Subject: Hello world!\r\n"+
    "\r\n"+
    "How are you today?";

// setup an event listener when the parsing finishes
mailparser.on("end", function(mail_object){
    console.log("From:", mail_object.from); //[{address:'sender@example.com',name:'Sender Name'}]
    console.log("Subject:", mail_object.subject); // Hello world!
    console.log("Text body:", mail_object.text); // How are you today?
});

// send the email source to the parser
mailparser.write(email);
mailparser.end();
```

What am i doing wrong?
Thx

Comment: I had the same initial problem. You installed the wrong mailparser library. You need to install mailparser-mit for this to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/), there's only two events: `headers` and `data`.

Perhaps it's easiest to use the [`simpleParser`](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/#simpleparser) instead of the lower-level (event-driven) [`MailParser`](https://nodemailer.com/extras/mailparser/#mailparser):

```
const simpleParser = require('mailparser').simpleParser;
...
simpleParser(email).then(function(mail_object) {
  console.log("From:", mail_object.from.value);
  console.log("Subject:", mail_object.subject);
  console.log("Text body:", mail_object.text);
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log('An error occurred:', err.message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP was asking about [mazira/mailparser-mit](https://github.com/mazira/mailparser-mit), which is a fork of the more popular [nodemailer/mailparser](https://github.com/nodemailer/mailparser).

The mainline `mailparser` has since switched back to the MIT license, and the `mailparser-mit` fork has not been updated in two years as of this writing.

Here's an example to get started with the lower-level `MailParser` class from the `mailparser` package:

```js
const {MailParser} = require('mailparser') // v3.0.1
const {createReadStream} = require('fs')

const parseEmail = async (readableStream) =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    readableStream
      .pipe(new MailParser())
      .on('headers', (headers) => console.log('headers', headers))
      .on('data', (data) => console.log('data', data))
      .on('error', reject)
      .on('end', resolve),
  )

parseEmail(createReadStream('emails/test1.eml'))
```